# How can I escape complex sql in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have the following sql (a simplification of the real problem):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE myname LIKE '%{$input}%';
```

How do I escape the $input?
I can't use the quoteInto (unless I miss something).
As

```
$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE myname LIKE '%?%'",$input);
```

Will give me

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE myname LIKE '%'my input'%';
```

and

```
$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE myname LIKE ?",'%'.$input.'%');
```

Will give me something on the lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE myname LIKE '\%my input\%';
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The last option is works out well for me i've not experienced it escaping '%'. So `$db->quote('%'.$_GET['query'].'%')` outputs `%queryvalue%`

Comment: FWIW, it outputs '%queryvalue%' including the single-quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is really simple. Zend_Db has een Expression class that helps you work arround it.

```
$select = $this->select()
->where('value LIKE("?")', new Zend_Db_Expr('%' . $value . '%'))

$this->fetchAll( $select );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the concatenation of $input at the SQL level:

```
$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM t WHERE myname LIKE '%'|| ? ||'%'",$input);
```

Unfortunately this isn't usable when you want $input to be able to contain literal ‘%’ or ‘_’ characters. To get round this, specify an explicit LIKE-ESCAPE character and escape them yourself:

```
$inputlike= '%'.preg_replace('[%_=]', '=$0', $input).'%';
$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT * FROM t WHERE myname LIKE ? ESCAPE '='", $inputlike);
```

(It can be any character, not necessarily '='. This also works around a bug where ESCAPE defaults to ‘\’ when not specified in MySQL.)

Unfortunately SQL Server also takes the ‘[’ character as special, to do a regexp-like character group. So if your DB is SQL Server you have to include ‘[’ in the group in preg_replace. Unfortunately it is not valid ANSL SQL to escape ‘[’ on other DBMSs where it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: And string concatenation is a DBMS-dependent, so check your DBMS docs.

Comment: Hmm, yeah... + is SQL Server and || is ANSI/everyone else, IIRC. Gah, what a mess.

Comment: A mess indeed. Will see what happens if I open a bug for that in the ZF project.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple:

```
$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE myname LIKE ?",'%' . $input . '%');

//Will output: SELECT FROM t WHERE myname LIKE '%inputtedvalue%'


$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE myname LIKE ?",'%' . $input);

//Will output: SELECT FROM t WHERE myname LIKE '%inputtedvalue'


$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE myname LIKE ?", $input . '%');

//Will output: SELECT FROM t WHERE myname LIKE 'inputtedvalue%'


$sql=$DB->quoteInto("SELECT *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE myname LIKE ?", $input);

//Will output: SELECT FROM t WHERE myname LIKE 'inputtedvalue'
```

What is the prolem?

:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, we'd like to escape LIKE special characters
Manually replacing them would be a bit dirty, but if there's no solution...

Answer (score 1):

It is more simple:

```
$table->select()->where("myname LIKE ?", '%'.$input.'%');
```

Answer (score -1):

you could just use the function that zf uses on the string which is addcslashes($value, "\000\n\r\'\"\032"); that would replace the string in the same way that zf uses or you could (in the case of mysql) use mysql_real_escape_string.

either way you wouldn't use one of the db quote functions

i do wonder if there's a method in the db class to do this but i don't know of one there should be though.